# Can't close userform while cursor blinks in a cell on worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I can't close a userform after i selected a cell and i double-clicked it to write something in it and the cursor blinks. I can't set focus back on userform to close it from the (x) button while the cursor blinks in cell. Is there a way to set focus back on userform while the cursor blinks in cell?

Comment: Try making the userform Modal. That means it can never lose focus(to a worksheet cell, or anything else in Excel) until you close it. Modal is the default state for UserForm.Show. I guess you have Modeless? Do you really need it?

Comment: I really need Modeless

Comment: I think (and someone can correct me if I'm wrong) that if you double-click in a cell to have the cursor there, Excel will freeze all other events until you exit the cell. Therefore what you're asking isn't possible. Maybe if you describe what you're actually trying to achieve, someone can suggest a better way?

Comment: I just want the user to be able to close the userform if it has decided that he wants to type something in the cell, while the cursor blinks in cell, or while he is wrinting in cell.